# Solving a system of equations with probability weights

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Fix any $w\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$.
Does there always exist $k\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough and some $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k\in (0,1)$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k p_i^j = w^{j-1}, \quad \text{for all } 1 \leq j \leq m+1 ~~ ?
$$
Maybe there is a way to answer this question with Vandermonde matrices ?

Comment: I think not, but cannot come up with a counterexample.

Comment: You have $k+1$ equations linking only $k$ unknowns.

Comment: It's a typo, there are m+1 equations but k+1 unknowns where k can be as large as we want.

Comment: A typo ? You are a joker, my friend.

Comment: Note that the first equation is just the second one for $j=1$, so you could have them both in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question for $m=2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582918/solving-a-system-of-3-equations-with-probability-weights)

Since the general system above include the restrictions imposed when $m=2$, there is a solution to the system if and only if $w = 1/\ell$ for some integer $\ell\geq 2$, and the solutions are of the form
$p_i = 1/\ell$ for a combination of $\ell$ ''$i$''s, and $p_{i'} = 0$ for $i'\neq i$.