# Solving a system of 3 equations with probability weights

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Fix any $w\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$.
Does there always exist $k\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough and some $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k\in (0,1)$ such that
$$
p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_k = 1
$$
$$
p_1^2 + p_2^2 + ... + p_k^2 = w
$$
$$
p_1^3 + p_2^3 + ... + p_k^3 = w^2
$$

?

Note : If $w = 1/k$, just take $p_1 = ... = p_k = 1/k$.

---

This is the case $m=2$ of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580749/solving-a-system-of-equations-with-probability-weights)

Comment: What do you think? You are more likely to get answers if you show you have put some effort into the problem yourself first

Comment: Also, you don't seem to be using your $m$ variable anywhere

Comment: I know that if $w = 1/k$, I can take $p_1 = ... = p_k = 1/k$.
I have no clue in the general case however

Comment: @lioness99a, this problem is the case $m = 2$ of the more general problem I posted yesterday. Better start with a easier problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
w^2 \stackrel{eq. 2}{=} \Big(\sum_{i=1}^k p_i^{3/2} p_i^{1/2}\Big)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^k p_i^3 \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \stackrel{eq. 1}{=} \sum_{i=1}^k p_i^3.
$$
Equation 3 requires that we have the equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and this happens if and only if $p_i^{3/2} = \lambda p_i$ for all $i\in \{1,2,\dots,k\}$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, namely $p_i = \lambda$ for all $i$ such that $p_i \neq 0$. If there are $\ell$ nonzero $p_i$'s, then by Equation 1, we have $p_i = 1/\ell$ for those.

In conclusion, there is a solution to the system (eq. 1, 2, 3) if and only if $w = 1/\ell$ for some integer $\ell\geq 2$.